# Determine <img> tag's final source, post-redirects

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's say I have a bit of HTML like so:

`<img id="picture" src="http://www.domain1.com/img.png"/>`

When the browser hits this domain1.com, it redirects to another URL, say "http://www.domain2.com/img2.png". And perhaps that URL redirects to some other domain, say "http://www.domain3.com/real_image.png".

Is there a way to use JavaScript to determine the URL of the final image (domain3.com)? `document.getElementById("picture").src` gives me the original URL (domain1.com).

Comment: Why aren't you using relative path?

Comment: Veeery interesting...and a nice question, +1

Comment: I think it depends greatly on *how* the redirects are handled.  Are the redirects done via a meta refresh tag, or server-side like with a .htacess file?

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to do it, as redirects are transparent to browsers.

Comment: @KatieK Images don't have meta tags.

Comment: You'd need to do this server-side.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319855/how-do-i-track-the-route-to-my-destination-page-from-various-301s

Comment: @Juhana - True, but a URI is a URI, and HTML docs do: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://thetudors.example.com/'" /> `

Comment: Yes, server-side. Because it might not be a simple redirect to a physical file. It could be a generated image (from DB etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be possible. Here's a jsfiddle that loads the google logo through a redirect:

http://jsfiddle.net/9BDbS/

I'm using `google.com` instead of `www.google.com` so you can see it actually returns a 301 redirect:

```
$ curl --head http://google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

If you take a look at the event object that I've logged to the console on image load, you won't find the `www.` version of the URL anywhere.